# How do I print a file from another branch with git?

Tags: git, sh

I know there's `git cat-file` but it takes a `sha`

what I want to do is something like `git cat-file mybranch -- path/to/myfile.txt` which would accomplish the same thing as

```
git checkout mybranch && cat path/to/myfile.txt
```

except it wouldn't actually checkout the branch. How can I do this?

Comment: Are you sure it accepts only a hash and not a revision in any form?

Comment: @MadPhysicist no I wasn't but I couldn't find docs that were telling me another way to do it, it appears I may have missed them.

Comment: Most git programs normalize their input. It's at least worth trying to see if it works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it in many ways:

```
git cat-file blob mybranch:path/to/myfile.txt
```

or

```
git show mybranch:path/to/myfile.txt
```